# three text input into one POST name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

If I have three text input and I want to combine the values in these three text input into one POST name, how can I do that?

**UPDATE:**

a good example would be if I have a phone number field, and I have three fields for the phone number... I wanted this to be posted as one so back in the server side I can just access it as $POST['phone']

Would be nice if something like jQuery can help me out here.

Comment: What language are you using server-side to handle the request?

Comment: I use PHP to handle the server-side request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have them as an array:

```
<input type="text" name="inputs[]" />
<input type="text" name="inputs[]" />
<input type="text" name="inputs[]" />
```

Then you can access them in the POST array.

You have not indicated the programming language, but in PHP it would be, `$_POST['inputs'][0]`, `$_POST['inputs'][1]`, `$_POST['inputs'][2]`...

---

Since you want to have only one phone input which contains the full phone number appear on server side, not parts of it, and you are using jQuery in your project, this will make things easy for you:

#### 1. Sample Markup

```
<form id="my_form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="phones[]" />
    <input type="text" name="phones[]" />
    <input type="text" name="phones[]" />
    <input type="hidden" name="phone" />
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send It" />
</form>
```

#### 2. jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $phones = $('#my_form input[name="phones[]"]'),
        $phone = $('#my_form input[name="phone"]');

    $('#my_form').submit(function(){
        // join all the phone parts together
        var phone_number = '';
        $phones.each(function(){
            phone_number += this.value;
        });

        // change the hidden input element's value
        $phone.val(phone_number);

        // remove the phone parts input elements
        $phones.remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: And in every other programming language you won't need to use the `[]` silliness on the end of the name in order to access them all.

Comment: yes, I am using PHP but please look at my update.. I want this to be on the server side before it can be accessed in the server

Comment: @aherlambang: What stops you from doing `$phone = implode($_POST['phone_parts']);`?

Comment: I have an already fixed .php that I can't modify.. and it takes the phone number as $_POST['phone']. However in the appearance client wants it as 3 separate text input

Comment: Then you will have to have a hidden input field: `<input type="hidden" name="phone" />`. And update its value via JavaScript, at the time the user enters the values. This is a hackish way to do it, but I would strongly suggest you change the PHP to handle this.

Comment: and is there a way so that the inputs[] is not posted?

Comment: @aherlambang: Also, use JavaScript to remove those input elements from the form at the form submit event.

Comment: if you can put this into code, I'd greatly appreciate it.. and accept your answer

Comment: @aherlambang: Do you use jQuery by chance in your project?

Comment: Yes, I use jQuery can I do something like this using jQuery @Shef?

Comment: @aherlambang: I posted the solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you would need to do that.

In php, you can do as Shef said.

In simple single word cases, you can concatenate them with some separator (e.g. # or $) and process the same on the server side.

Comment: a good example would be if I have a phone number field, and I have three fields for the phone number... I wanted this to be posted as one so back in the server side I can just access it as $POST['phone']